# Google Search Console API Results Two Days Behind the Site. How to Fix?

Tags: google-search-api, google-search-console

So I just started working with the Google Search Console API to see top keywords that sent people to a site and interestingly, when I use the API, the most recent data I can get is from two days ago, but if I go directly into the search console website as a user, I can get data from today.

Is there a way to fix this or is it a known limitation? I Know there's a 48-hour delay in getting the search console data into Google Analytics, but I thought that applied only to the GA / Search console connection.

Comment: The API has not been updated for quite a while, I think before they shortened the delay in the website reports. So I suspect it is still limited to the old delay times.

Answer (score 1):

Simple! You just have to define the value for `dataState` as `all` to include this [fresh data](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query#:%7E:text=dataState,only%20finalized%20data.) you're referring to.